# ngsx and Angular version 5.5

Tags: angular, package.json

I had some problems installing and setting up ngxs in the first place. I compared my package.json file with the one from ngsx github master and saw that most of the install where at v6+.  I get this strange error message: ...TS2305..rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'OperatorFunction'. rxjs version = 5.5.6. 
I solved the problem by copying the package.json file from ngsx master, but I'm trying to dig in what really happened..:-) Here is a copy of the two package.json files. One is working the other is not.

It's obvious that there are version differences, but I have tried to replace most of the angular stuff i the not working version, but still get same error. Wonder if ngsx is VERY sensitive on say rxjs version etc.

`THIS IS NOT WORKING: "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@ngxs/logger-plugin": "^3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.0.0-rc.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
THIS IS WORKING: 
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0-rc.3",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^6.1.3",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^6.1.3",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.29.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~9.6.0",
    "@types/semver": "^5.5.0",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "fs-extra": "^5.0.0",
    "husky": "^0.15.0-rc.13",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lint-staged": "^7.0.0",
    "mock-socket": "^7.1.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^2.3.0",
    "prettier": "^1.8.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0-rc.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-beta.1",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tsickle": "^0.27.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@ngxs/logger-plugin": "^3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.0.0-rc.1"
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Just need to update RxJS version. I upgraded it to ^5.6.0-forward-compat.4 and no more error.

[[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGj11j4hxmg)]